# Use of a connector beyond OEM's voltage rating

Tags: connector, maximum-ratings

I've been looking for some time for a suitable connector for my device, and happened upon a seemingly perfect option. It has the right number of pins, the right mix between signal and power pins, the right footprint. the right mounting type and the right price point. The connector is designed for automotive use, and is only rated to 14VDC by the OEM. My device is rated to ~27VDC, but would operate in the 12-14VDC range during normal operation.

What are my options in terms of using this connector? I've reached out to the OEM, with the aim of discussing this issue with an engineer, but I've so far only received sales support and 'here are the emails of our distributors'. Would an alternative option be to independently test/verify the use of the connector at my intended voltage rating?

The OEM rates the power inputs (2.8mm blades) to 25A and the signal inputs (0.64" pins) to 11A. I don't expect to exceed 12A on the power inputs or more than 3A on the signal pins. I only expect the voltage to exceed 14VDC during fault conditions.

Comment: [What wire gauge is used?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108159/142621)

Comment: Thanks for the link. The signal pins use 18awg wire, and the 2.8mm power blades accommodate a 14awg wire. The OEM rates the power pins to 25A and the signal pins to 11A; I won't see currents anywhere near that high.

Comment: Is it possible to alter your question so it is less similar to that one. The company has sent you a 'this is what we were told' type answer because they don't want to accept liability. I don't have an improvement to that accepted answer. How often and how long you plan going to 27 volts is also a factor, otherwise I'd say don't worry about less than 10% overvoltage; especially at low amperage (a value not included in your question).

Comment: I've added some further detail to the question. I can't think of a suitable amended question however; my question is about device rating, not about wiring gauge selection (I'm very comfortable with the wiring size). I understand it's a question of liability. Assuming I won't get anywhere with the OEM, is independent testing/verification of the component an option?

Comment: How does the OEM set the voltage rating?  I suspect that they design to a voltage (application) in mind, choose a set of specifications and then set creep distances, materials and air gaps accordingly. Then they might test. You'll need to convince yourself that you can relax the specifications of the original design and that the creep distances and gaps are appropriate to your application.

Comment: Your biggest problem is likely to be arcing is the user disconnects the connector under load.  DC is much more prone to arcing than AC, which is why manufacturers specify such low voltages.  The connector may operate fine many times if disconnected under load, but each time the pins will get a bit more damaged by the arc.

Comment: @DDuck This is the exact question I've asked of the OEM. I suspect they've designed the product for a given voltage, applied some headroom, and tested/verified that figure. I've made some headway with the OEM's engineering department, so hopefully they can provide some input.

Comment: @SimonB Understood. Thankfully my application is a somewhat 'set and forget' affair, but I understand that any issues arising from connecting/disconnecting need to be addressed regardless. As per above, I'll certainly raise this topic with the OEM, if I get that far.

Comment: "I only expect the voltage to exceed 14VDC during fault conditions". The "fault condition" is a key here. For example electrical plug and/or wires in low power device (like shaver) will most likely be damaged if short-circuited, which is a fault condition. Depending on your application it could be perfectly OK to design for normal operating conditions and add safety features to deal with faults. Does not mean the device should survive the fault, only that it does not present a safety hazard when it dies.