# Segmented Wire Gauge and DC Current Capacity

Tags: batteries, wire, gauge

I am working on a project that brings power from a car battery inside the vehicle and to a DC-DC charger. The DC-DC charger then takes the power and charges a second battery. The system is rated at 25A.

The attached schematic tells the story. The DC-DC device comes with 8 gauge wires already. I am wondering if 10 gauge wires can be used on segment S3b.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell what gauge wire I need?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108144/how-do-i-tell-what-gauge-wire-i-need)

Comment: @Farzad Please as a specific question

Comment: The links provided to similar past questions are full of knowledge and wisdom I am sure, and I totally understand the policies of this network, but the difficulty of it is that I would need to get out of my own head and get into theirs in order to first understand what the question was about, then read all the answers to determine if somewhere within those discussions there is a solution for what is in my head - and by then I probably have forgotten that one. So, I will try to read them. The best thing I have thought about is just test a wire segment under a load and see what happens. Thanks.